# copying files from one user to another in ubunta in the same machine

Tags: server

I am copying files from one user to another in ubunta in the same machine. my file is .pdf . I use this command

cp /home/USER1/hello.pdf /home/USER2/hello.pdf

but I got this error cp: target âScanningâ is not a directory

could uou help me ?

Comment: Fairly certain that you simply specify the directory to which you need it copied. You don't specify the file name.

Comment: I mean, `cp /home/USER1/hello.pdf /home/USER2/`

Comment: The command I just told you is how `cp` works. You copy into a directory, not to a filename. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-copy-file-command/

Comment: @Zacharee1 I make folder cp /home/maryl/hello.pdf home/ros/newfolder

Comment: I'll write an answer.

Comment: If I helped, I would really appreciate it if you pressed the little checkmark under the vote arrows on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `cp` command is expecting a directory as the output, not a file. Instead of `cp /home/maryl/hello.pdf /home/ros/newfolder/hello.pdf` you need `cp /home/maryl/hello.pdf /home/ros/newfolder/`. The destination has to be a directory. The command takes the file you specify and copies it into the directory your tell it. Just for reference (although it seems you've figured it out mostly), the command is formatted as

```
cp /path/to/source.txt /path/to/destination_dir/
```

Options, such as `-r`, can be used if you want to copy directories. Refer [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-copy-file-command/) for more info.